# vagrantとvirtualboxを使ってkusanagiでの環境構築時のエラー

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

#### 前提・実現したいこと

仮想マシンの起動を行いたい、

https://kusanagi.tokyo/cloud/kusanagi-for-vagrant/
の支持に従って、作業をすすめる中、
コマンドプロンプトでvagrant upを入力した際に、下記のエラーが発生

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージの日本語訳

エラーメッセージ

```
ボックス「primestrategy / kusanagi」が見つからなかったか、
リモートカタログでアクセスできませんでした。これがプライベートの場合
HashiCorpのVagrantCloudのボックスで、経由でログインしていることを確認してください
`vagrantlogin`。また、名前を再確認してください。拡張された
URLとエラーメッセージを以下に示します。

URL：["https://vagrantcloud.com/primestrategy/kusanagi"]
エラー：SSL証明書の問題：証明書チェーン内の自己署名証明書
```

実行したコマンド

```
kei-no-MacBook-Air:~ kei$ cd /Users/kei/Desktop/
kei-no-MacBook-Air:Desktop kei$ mkdir ko-dhinngukadaisho-go
kei-no-MacBook-Air:Desktop kei$ cd ko-dhinngukadaisho-go
kei-no-MacBook-Air:ko-dhinngukadaisho-go kei$ vagrant init primestrategy/kusanagi
A `Vagrantfile` has been placed in this directory. You are now
ready to `vagrant up` your first virtual environment! Please read
the comments in the Vagrantfile as well as documentation on
`vagrantup.com` for more information on using Vagrant.
kei-no-MacBook-Air:ko-dhinngukadaisho-go kei$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'primestrategy/kusanagi' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
The box 'primestrategy/kusanagi' could not be found or
could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private
box on HashiCorp's Vagrant Cloud, please verify you're logged in via
`vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded
URL and error message are shown below:

URL: ["https://vagrantcloud.com/primestrategy/kusanagi"]
Error: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
```

#### 試したこと

以前、Vagrantfileのconfig.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"の部分の33を56にしたら上手く行ったので変更してみたが、効果なし、様々なサイトのやり方を試すも、何かしらのエラーが出てしまい先に進めない。

#### 補足情報

ワードプレスで、ウェブサイトを作ろうとしています。
今現在、サイト制作初心者ですので、専門的な横文字には明るくありません。

マックを使用、また最近インストールしたばかりの、vagrantとvirtualboxを使用しています。

うまくいかない場合はさきほどVagrantfileを作成したディレクトリがカレントディレクリになっているか確認して下さい。とありますが、pwdコマンドで確認したところ問題ありません、こう出ます。

```
kei-no-MacBook-Air:ko-dhinngukadaisho-go kei$ pwd
/Users/kei/Desktop/ko-dhinngukadaisho-go
```

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/373424) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Comment: "self signed certificate in certificate chain" とあるとおり、OSに自己署名証明書をインストールしているのが原因かなと思いますが、心当たりあるでしょうか。 [こちら](https://reject.tokyo/vagrant-error-ssl/) や [こちら](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42718527/4506703) にあるような insecure オプションを追加すればダウンロードできそうに思われます。(追記: アンチウィルスソフトが原因でこのエラーが出ることもあるような記述も見かけました)

Comment: 皆さんご回答いただき、ありがとうございました。